# Vaadin 10+: How do I handle uncaught exceptions?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

In Vaadin 8:

```
UI.getCurrent().setErrorHandler(e -> handleError(e));
```

`setErrorHandler` does not exist in Vaadin 11, and I cannot find a corresponding method or documentation.

Answer (score 3):

In Flow (Vaadin 10+) there is a mechanism that catches uncaught exceptions in Router. So you can create error views, which are shown when defined exception is captured. They are created by implementing HasErrorParameter interface typed with the exception. Below is an example from Vaadin documentation:

```
@Tag(Tag.DIV)
public class RouteNotFoundError extends Component
        implements HasErrorParameter<NotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public int setErrorParameter(BeforeEnterEvent event,
            ErrorParameter<NotFoundException> parameter) {
        getElement().setText("Could not navigate to '"
                    + event.getLocation().getPath() + "'");
        return HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
    }
}
```

I recommend to read more from the documentation.

https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-exception-handling.html

Comment: Thank you. I implemented a custom navigation scheme in Vaadin 8, so I am not using Router in Vaadin 11, but VaadinServlet and UI. Still looking for a way to show a message to the user when an exception happens.

Comment: Reto, Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

There is VaadinSession::setErrorHandler for cases where it is not about an error that happens during routing / navigating but, for example, when clicking.

Comment: You have to implement a SessionInitListener and then configure your errorHandler...

Comment: How would it be to implement a SessionInitListener?

Comment: Please see https://mvysny.github.io/vaadin-error-handling/ for help on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vaadin Spring Boot starter implementation should look like this:

```
@SpringComponent
public class MyVaadinServiceInitListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener {

    @Override
    public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
        event.getSource().addSessionInitListener(e -> {
            e.getSession().setErrorHandler(errorEvent-> {
                Throwable t = errorEvent.getThrowable();
                // handle error
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way and for me it didn't catch the error. Would you have more details on this alternative?

Comment: This is no longer possible in Vaadin Flow.

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin 10+ there are two error handling entrypoints:

- The router exception handling, triggered during the navigation phase when the view is constructed, and
- Session’s ErrorHandler, triggered after the view has been rendered.

The former one is triggered when the server failed to produce a view because of an exception. The latter one is triggered by exceptions originating from button clicks, other kinds of component events, and by UI.access().

Please see https://mvysny.github.io/vaadin-error-handling/ for more details.